# Ensure difference between adjoining elements in PySpark array is more than a given minimum value

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe (`df`) with three columns.

1.
`category` : Some string

2.
`startTimeArray` : It is an array which contains timestamps in ascending order.

3.
`endTimeArray` : It is an array which contains timestamps in ascending order.

In each row, the length of array in `startTimeArray` is the same as the length of array in `endTimeArray`. For each index in these arrays the timestamp given in `startTimeArray` is less (occurs at a previous date) than the corresponding (same index) timestamp in `endTimeArray`.

In the column `startTimeArray` (and the column `endTimeArray`), the lengths of the arrays can be different.

Following is an example of the dataframe:

```py
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|category|startTimeArray                                                                                           |endTimeArray                                                                                             |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|a       |[2019-01-10 00:00:00, 2019-01-12 00:00:00, 2019-01-16 00:00:00, 2019-01-20 00:00:00]                     |[2019-01-11 00:00:00, 2019-01-15 00:00:00, 2019-01-18 00:00:00, 2019-01-22 00:00:00]                     |
|a       |[2019-03-11 00:00:00, 2019-03-18 00:00:00, 2019-03-20 00:00:00, 2019-03-25 00:00:00, 2019-03-27 00:00:00]|[2019-03-16 00:00:00, 2019-03-19 00:00:00, 2019-03-23 00:00:00, 2019-03-26 00:00:00, 2019-03-30 00:00:00]|
|b       |[2019-01-14 00:00:00, 2019-01-16 00:00:00, 2019-02-22 00:00:00]                                          |[2019-01-15 00:00:00, 2019-01-18 00:00:00, 2019-02-25 00:00:00]                                          |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In each row, in the column `startTimeArray` , I want to make sure that the difference between consecutive elements (elements at consecutive indices) in the array is at least three days. If a row in `startTimeArray` has `n` elements, I am open to the deletion of entries in the array, except the first entry. Additionally, if an element at index i is deleted from a row in `startTimeArray`, I would like the element at index i-1 to be deleted from the same row in `endTimeArray`.**

How can I achieve this task using PySpark?

A few things, we need to note:

1. If an array in `startTimeArray` has one element, we just let it be there.
2. I realize that this task can be realized by deleting all elements after the first element in arrays in `startTimeArray`. That would be the trivial case. But I want to achieve the task by making as few deletions as possible.

Following is the output that I want in the case of the example dataframe `df` given above.

```py
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|category|startTimeArray                                                 |endTimeArray                                                   |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|a       |[2019-01-10 00:00:00, 2019-01-16 00:00:00, 2019-01-20 00:00:00]|[2019-01-15 00:00:00, 2019-01-18 00:00:00, 2019-01-22 00:00:00]|
|a       |[2019-03-11 00:00:00, 2019-03-18 00:00:00, 2019-03-25 00:00:00]|[2019-03-16 00:00:00, 2019-03-23 00:00:00, 2019-03-30 00:00:00]|
|b       |[2019-01-14 00:00:00, 2019-02-22 00:00:00]                     |[2019-01-18 00:00:00, 2019-02-25 00:00:00]                     |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user-defined function (UDF) could do the job. While it comes with a performance penalty over native Spark sql functions, it expresses the desired operations clearly.

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

d = [date(2019, 1, d) for d in (10, 12, 16, 20)]
e = [date(2019, 1, d) for d in (11, 15, 18, 22)]
f = [date(2019, 3, d) for d in (11, 18, 20, 25, 27)]
g = [date(2019, 3, d) for d in (16, 19, 23, 26, 30)]
h = [date(2019, 1, 14), date(2019, 1, 16), date(2019, 2, 22)]
i = [date(2019, 1, 15), date(2019, 1, 18), date(2019, 2, 25)]

df = spark.createDataFrame((("a", d, e), ("a", f, g), ("b", h, i)),
                           schema=("category", "startDates", "endDates"))


@udf(returnType=ArrayType(ArrayType(DateType())))
def retain_dates_n_days_apart(startDates, endDates, min_apart=3):
    start_dates = [startDates[0]]
    end_dates = []
    for start, end in zip(startDates[1:], endDates):
        if start >= start_dates[-1] + timedelta(days=min_apart):
            start_dates.append(start)
            end_dates.append(end)
    end_dates.append(endDates[-1])
    return start_dates, end_dates


df2 = (df
       .withColumn("foo",
                   retain_dates_n_days_apart(df.startDates,
                                             df.endDates))
       .cache())

(df2.withColumn("startDates", df2.foo.getItem(0))
 .withColumn("endDates", df2.foo.getItem(1))
 .drop("foo")
 ).show(truncate=False)
# +--------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
# |category|startDates                          |endDates                            |
# +--------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
# |a       |[2019-01-10, 2019-01-16, 2019-01-20]|[2019-01-15, 2019-01-18, 2019-01-22]|
# |a       |[2019-03-11, 2019-03-18, 2019-03-25]|[2019-03-16, 2019-03-23, 2019-03-30]|
# |b       |[2019-01-14, 2019-02-22]            |[2019-01-18, 2019-02-25]            |
# +--------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```